# Como declarar rotas que são armazenadas em cache e outras rotas que não são armazenadas?

Tags: vue.js, single-page-application, service-worker

Bom dia. 
Estou desenvolvendo um sistema SPA cujo uma parte fica disponivel apenas quando o usuario estiver online e outra fica disponivel mesmo offline. 
A parte offline é configurada na service worker mas um problema começou a surgir. Rotas da aplicação que usa micro service para dispor os dados que são usados para montar a pagina acabam sendo armazenado em cache. O que gera uma situação inesperada.

A aplicação conta com o service worker instalado da seguinte forma:

```
var version = '0.8';
self.addEventListener('install', function (event) {
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.open('v1').then(function (cache) {
            return cache.addAll([
                '/',
                '/css/app.css',
                '/js/app.js',
                '/cache.js',
                '/favicon.ico',
                '/js/gauge.min.js',
                '/manifest.json',
                '/avatar.png',
            ]);
        })
    );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
    event.respondWith(
        caches.open('mysite-dynamic').then(function (cache) {
            return cache.match(event.request).then(function (response) {
                if (response) {
                    return response;
                } else {
                    return fetch(event.request).then(function (response) {
                        cache.put(event.request, response.clone());
                        return response;
                    });
                }
            });
        })
    );
});
```

Com este código a parte tanto offline fica disponível para o usuário. O problema que todas dos micro service também são roteadas pelo cache. Todas as rotas dos micro services são do tipo https://site/api/*
Este problema não conseguir encontrar informação nem na documentação, nem nos sites de tutorial.

E com isto. O grande X da questão é que rotas da api não permitem mais de um cadastro no sistema por exemplo. Logo. Sempre que eu acesso a pagina, rotas de post são cacheadas. e só consigo cadastrar uma entidade  no sistema, pq o navegador faz o cache e não me permite mais mandar rotas post para o servidor.

Haveria um modo da service worker ser configurada para funcionar provendo dados exclusivamente quando o sistema estiver inacessivel? Isto é, quando os recursos não puderem ser acessados?

Comment: Eu realmente não consegui entender seu problema!

Comment: Deixei um pouco mais claro com o ultimo paragrafo. Mas em resumo. A minha api que é RestFul tá tendo suas rotas cacheadas. Assim não consigo manter os dados sincronizados a medida que o usuário acessa o sistema.

Answer (score 0):

Depois de diversas pesquisa mesmo que não ficou realmente claro acreditei que a service worker estava armazenando os dados e estes dados sempre eram priorizado ao invés do retorno do servidor.

Neste aspecto consegui configurar o meu cache de tal forma que o problema desapareceu, Não ficou para mim bem claro o pq que resolveu, mas irei postar o código da service worker para futuras busca para solucionar este tipo de erro.

```
var version = '0.8'; //Corrigido o erro de cache
self.addEventListener('install', function (event) {
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.open('v1').then(function (cache) {
            return cache.addAll([
                '/',
                '/css/app.css',
                '/js/app.js',
                '/cache.js',
                '/favicon.ico',
                '/js/gauge.min.js',
                '/manifest.json',
                '/avatar.png',
            ]);
        })
    );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
    event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request)
            .then(function (response) {
                // Cache hit - return response
                if (response) {
                    return response;
                }
                return fetch(event.request);
            }
            )
    );
});
```